# Loop interface, depending on a called variable (Flask)

Tags: python, flask, logic

I'm having problem developing a flask code app where I need to use the while statement. According to this code, I want to repeat the return depending on the "x" and "i" value. The app runs correctly, but it only returns the first value (I believe is not returning to the while statement because "i" is not changing its value). Here is the code:

```
from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__) #create the Flask app
app.secret_key = "hello"

@app.route('/begin') #allow both GET and POST requests
def form():
    x = 4
    i = 1

    while i <= x:

        return '''The value is : '''+str(i)+'''\n'''
        i += 1

    else:
        return '''done.'''

    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
  app.run(debug=True, port=5000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
@app.route('/begin')
def form():
    x = 4
    i = 1
    rv = ''
    while i <= x:

        rv = rv + '''The value is : '''+str(i)+'''\n'''
        i += 1

    return rv + '''done.'''
```

After you hit a return statement, the function halts at that point. In addition, you don't need an else statement after a while, or the pass command.

In addition, if you really do want to allow post and get requests, you need to do the following:

```
@app.route('/begin', methods=['get', 'post'])
```

As by default, only get requests are allowed.

Comment: Thank you very much! You solved my problem!!